# Azure - deploying SQL Virtual Machine with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-database, virtual-machine

I am trying to deploy an SQL Virtual Machine using terraform and I am getting the error explained below.

If anyone else experienced this error and knows what is the issue here, please help.

Thanks

`│ Error: creating Sql Virtual Machine (Subscription: "33f912" │ Resource Group Name: "RG_TEST" │ Sql Virtual Machine Name: "we-test-01"): polling after CreateOrUpdate: Code="Ext_AutomatedBackupError" Message="Error: 'Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.'" │ │   with module.sql.azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.this["sql_vm_01"], │   on .terraform/modules/sql/main.tf line 263, in resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "this": │  263: resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "this" {`

If I try to create the VM with no extra configurations, it works just fine.

When I enable the following attribute, it starts failing (basically trying to customize the collation, not go with the Default one):

`collation = "Latin1_General_BIN"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below **Terraform code** to deploy **SQL Virtual Machine** in Azure.

Main.tf:

```
  provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "sqlrg" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "sqlvnet" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-VN"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "sqlsubnet" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-SN"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.sqlvnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "sqlnic" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.sqlsubnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.sqlnsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vm" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-PIP"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "sqlnsg" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-NSG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "RDPRule" {
  name                        = "RDPRule"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
  priority                    = 1000
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = 3389
  source_address_prefix       = "167.220.255.0/25"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.sqlnsg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "MSSQLRule" {
  name                        = "MSSQLRule"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
  priority                    = 1001
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = 1433
  source_address_prefix       = "167.220.255.0/25"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.sqlnsg.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "sqlnic" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-NIC"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "exampleconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.sqlsubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.vm.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "sqlnsggroup" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.sqlnic.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.sqlnsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-VM"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.sqlnic.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS14_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
    offer     = "SQL2017-WS2016"
    sku       = "SQLDEV"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${var.prefix}-OSDisk"
    caching           = "ReadOnly"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "winhost01"
    admin_username = "exampleadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    timezone                  = "Pacific Standard Time"
    provision_vm_agent        = true
    enable_automatic_upgrades = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.sqlvm.id
  sql_license_type   = "PAYG"
}
```

**Var.tf**

```
variable "location" {
description = "Azure location."
}
variable "prefix" {
description = "NetApp Account"
}
```

**Terraform Plan**

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code, **SQL VM** got created sucessfully as below.

[image]

Refer: [terraform-provider-azurerm/variables.tf at main · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/main/examples/mssql/mssqlvm)  created by ceciliasharp.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how does this solve/answer my question? Have you actually read it properly?

Comment: Hi Sorin lonescu, kindly add your Terraform code in qns to check the cause of error.